# Open Reading Frame Finder for DNA Sequence: How to start off?

Tags: python

I know this might not be the place, but I'm stuck in how to start off in designing a Open Reading Frame finder. I saw in other questions that BioPython is useful, but I want to build it from the ground up. But, I'm stuck on how too. Any help would be appreciated!

I know you want to start off by finding a start codon in the reading frame you are in, and once you find it to possibly append it to a list and carry on till you get to a stop codon.

Comment: Start from here https://kaspermunch.wordpress.com/2013/11/19/finding-open-reading-frames/

Comment: How would I take the start codon positions and stop codon positions to produce a string of the DNA seq for the ORFs?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a very useful [reference](https://a-little-book-of-r-for-bioinformatics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/chapter7.html) for open reading frame finding from scratch; but this is written with R and can be adapted to Python: